# get the state of the user (DISABLED/ENABLED) when triggers lamda function of pre sign in

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have an user with the state `Disabled` in his account:

[image]

I have this `lamda` function in the event of `pre sign in`:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 console.log(event);
 callback(null, event);
};
```

when the user try to `sign in`, I can get this response of the `lamda` that I have created
`console.log` of event:

```
{
 version: '1',
 region: 'us-east-1',
 userPoolId: 'us-east-1_XXXXXXXXX',
 userName: 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX',
 callerContext: {
 awsSdkVersion: 'aws-sdk-unknown-unknown',
 clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
},
 triggerSource: 'PostAuthentication_Authentication',
 request: {
 userAttributes: {
  sub: 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-aXX-XXXXXXXXXXX',
  'custom:city_id': '141',
  'cognito:email_alias': 'gaby@hotmail.com',
  'cognito:user_status': 'CONFIRMED',
  birthdate: '1998-08-18',
  email_verified: 'false',
  gender: 'male',
  phone_number_verified: 'true',
  'custom:uid': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  given_name: 'Gabo',
  'custom:document_number': '1053817459',
  'custom:status': 'activo',
  phone_number: '+999999999',
  family_name: 'Amaya',
  email: 'gaby@hotmail.com',
  'custom:document_type_id': '1',
  'custom:country_code': 'CO'
 },
 newDeviceUsed: false
},
response: {}
}
```

How can I get in my `lamda` function the status of his account? (the status is `Disabled`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) method to pass the username and user pool ID and get their details as response. This method also returns if the user is enabled or disabled in the form of boolean. eg: Enabled : True

Comment: Than you for answering, but the idea is get this data within of the lamda function

Comment: You can put the method i mentioned in your lambda. Your lambda gets the username from the event, right?